# PGF: Externalize + Fadings differences in viewer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, viewers, tikz-external

I've been working with the `fadings` library in PGF and I was having trouble getting it working with externalize.

I finally figured out that it was working, but Apple's Preview does not display the fadings when externalized. I opened the PDF with Adobe Acrobat and the fadings worked fine.

Has anyone else come across this or know if it's a bug in PGF or Apple's Preview?

Here's an example using `\includegraphics` and `\pgfuseimage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
% Three color triangles
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4) -- cycle;
\fill[blue,path fading=west] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4) -- cycle;
\fill[red,path fading=south] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics{\jobname-figure0.pdf}
\pgfdeclareimage{fig0}{\jobname-figure0.pdf}
\pgfuseimage{fig0}
\end{document}
```

Left is Adobe Acrobat, right is Apple Preview:

[image]

edit:
Next is comparison between the above document in Preview and the externalized image also in Preview

[image]

Comment: This is fairly well known.  Fadings do not work well with some pdf viewers.

Comment: Thanks. However, I want to make clear that fadings _does_ work in Preview, just not when externalized and re-imported. In fact, the standalone pdf will show up correctly in Preview and looks identical to the Acrobat rendering (I guess I should have included that comparison as well).

Comment: [unrelated to question]: funny, I have just finished the documentation of pgfplots surface plots with explicitly given color (such as a surface patch with three corners and colors red, green, blue) http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots_unstable.pdf . The outcome of those patch shadings is identical to your overlaid fadings for this special case :)

Comment: :) It _is_ a nice looking triangle and a good addition to the pgfplots doc. I should have mentioned that the triangle I used is originally from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/rgb-triangle/

Comment: @Liam well, I added it to the pgfplots doc. However, the way pgfplots achieves this type of shading is substantially different. It would be done by means of `\addplot coordinates {
    (90,4) [color=red]
    (210,4) [color=green]
    (-30,4) [color=blue]
};` and a suitable set of options (taken from the manual).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue in Preview's handling of valid PDF output, not generating the output in TeX.
